# Ubuntu 23.10 google account always logout after closing browser

Tags: browser, google, 23.10

im facing some issues trying to keep my google account logged in.Every time i close any browser(tried brave and firefox) in ubuntu my google account just logout , already checked if my browser is set to delete my cookie info after close.This problem only happens with the google account (youtube and stuff). Already tried to set google for always allow cookies and site data exceptions.